# Left adjoint to forgetful from modules to abelian groups

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-groups

What is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U : R-\mathsf{Mod} \to \mathsf{Ab}$? Note here that $R$ is a general ring, not necessarily commutative. I've seen that they define it as $F A = R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} A$, however, this tensor only works if $R$ is commutative, doesn't it? Or is $R$ considered with the addition instead of multiplication? How can I prove this is the free construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $R$ is being considered as a right $\mathbb Z$-module in the obvious way. There is a natural isomorphism $\phi:\hom_R(R\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A,B)\to\hom_{\mathbb Z}(A,B)$ for all abelian groups $A$ and all $R$-modules $B$ such that $\phi(f)(a)=f(1\otimes a)$. The inverse map $\psi$ is such that $\psi(f)(r\otimes a)=rf(a)$. You should check that these functions are both well-defined, that they are mutually inverse and that they are natural in both $A$ and $B$. That will give you what you want.